Server error when using Azureb2c provider with next-auth.js
I am getting the following error when I attempt to login from AzureB2C using next-auth.js:

I created an AzureADB2C tenant according the instructions provided by Microsoft. I then created the application registration and user flow for sign-in. This all works when I test the user flow using https://jw.ms as the end-point.
I added the following redirect URI's as Web endpoints (not SPA endpoints) and enabled implicit grant and hybrid flows:

http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azureb2c
http://localhost:3000/auth

I then cloned the next-auth.js project and updated the environment variables and auth.ts to use the AzureB2C provider using these instructions. When I run the application, I am able to click on the sign-in button that displays "Sign in with Azure Active Directory B2C".  But when I click on the button, I get the server error message.
Here is my auth configuration:
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import AzureB2C from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad-b2c"
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"

export const config = {
  theme: { logo: "https://authjs.dev/img/logo-sm.png" },
  providers: [
    AzureB2C({
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME,
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET,
      primaryUserFlow: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW,
      authorization: { params: { scope: "offline_access openid" } },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  basePath: "/auth",
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ request, auth }) {
      const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
      if (pathname === "/middleware-example") return !!auth
      return true
    },
    jwt({ token, trigger, session }) {
      if (trigger === "update") token.name = session.user.name
      return token
    },
  },
} satisfies NextAuthConfig

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config)


I have no idea on how to check the server logs, but when I check the audit log for Azure ADB2C I see the following for this login:



Date
Service
Category
Activity
Status
Status Reason
Target(s)




...
Core Directory
ApplicationManagement
Update Application
Success
(blank)
my B2C domain


...
Core Directory
ApplicationManagement
Update Service Principal
Success
(blank)
my B2C domain



The page I'm redirected to is http://localhost:3000/auth/error?error=Configuration so I'm assuming my auth.ts configuration is not correct?
The auth route is: https://localhost:3000/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts (this is as configured in the example code):
import { handlers } from "auth"
export const { GET, POST } = handlers


I tried logging in via AzureADB2C on the next-auth demo: https://next-auth-example.vercel.app/auth/ and it throws the same error.  So I am now working on the assumption that this is being caused by a but in the next-auth AzureADB2C provider and not my code.
